# Replace ViewController from existing navigation hierarchy

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

i'm performing some task in my ViewControllers in this pattern 
`A` -> `b`->`c` (here A,B and C are representing my different ViewControllers)

once i'm done at `C` i'm performing a segue to get to ViewController `D` now i want to change the effect of back button here , so that when users taps on back button ViewController `1`  should open instead of `C`

i found some similar posts and one of them was suggesting to change the root so i tried this :
in my ViewController `D`

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if (cameAfterCreatingNewTag){

        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TrendingVC")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController;
        cameAfterCreatingNewTag = false 
     }

 }
```

but it didnt worked my navigation bar disappeared and also viewController `1` get opened. (which is not expected behavior , i wanted to open VC `1` when i tap on back button from VC `D`)

anyone knows how to fix this ? or there's any other proper way to do it ?

Comment: Are these view controllers contained by a `UINavigationController`?  If so, the navigation controller has a property called `viewControllers` which can be replaced.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers

Comment: Yes they are all embed into a UINavigationcontroller .

Comment: Good. Get the viewControllers array from the nav controller, make a mutableCopy, change it as you see fit.  Set the changed array back on the nav vc

Comment: Alright , replace the existing array of VC with desired once right ?

Comment: thanks man @danh , working fine now appreciate your effort man